# Is it always possible to visually determine if it's gas or electic stove?

Tags: stove, gas, electric-stoves

I saw stoves with flat glass-like surface and there red glowing circles inside when they're on. Are those a gas stoves? Are there gas stoves with fire inside or those flat stoves are all electric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gas stoves will always have "open" heating elements because the gas requires oxygen in order to burn and generate heat. Anytime you see a closed, glassed-over heating element, the heat is electric in source. However without more information about the design of the stove, it can't really be determined whether the heat is a traditional radiant heat element or an induction element (in which case the red glow may be cosmetic, generated only by lights to indicate that the burner is on).

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you ever seen induction stoves with cosmetic lights?

Comment: @rumtscho Not personally, but I've talked with other home cooks who've reported seeing them. I don't know if all or even most induction stoves do this but it makes sense as a visual indicator that most stove users would understand intuitively.

Comment: Samsung, at least, has had induction burners with LEDs providing a "heating" indicator since 2014: https://gizmodo.com/fake-led-flames-indicate-how-hot-samsungs-new-induction-1649057270